# How to use "iota.lib.js.powsrvio" via a small device supports LoraWAN?

Tags: proof-of-work, energy-consumption

If we want PoW is **not** performed in the device (in particular for low energy devices) we can use `iota.lib.js.powsrvio`.

How to use `powsrv.io`? And what are prerequirements ? (Assume we want to use it in a small device supports **LoraWAN**. You can see an example of this small device here: [Link to the device](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/TTGO-T-Deer-Pro-mini-LoRa-433MHz-868MHz-915MHz-Mega328-for-arduino/32948588389.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.27424c4dSUGiJN).)

For more information, please see following article :
https://medium.com/@harmvandenbrink/lorawan-and-iota-proof-of-concept-of-storing-data-in-real-time-in-the-tangle-9ba6a109b552

Comment: If you can install and use NodeJS + npm on the device, you can use the library. Otherwise no.

Comment: @kfx , That's exactly my question: Is it possible to install IOTA on a LoraWAN device? (According to IOTA implementation versions in its official Github repository (https://github.com/iotaledger)) Thanks

Comment: There's no such thing as a "LoraWAN device". There are some devices that can support the LoRaWAN Class A, Class B or Class C functionality. Be more specific what you need. In any case, the particular library you mention depends on NodeJS & its infrastructure.

Comment: @kfx OK.I used the same term of the article (where _Harm van den Brink_ (a IOTA foundation member) says _"The LoraWAN device I used bought at AliExpress →  [Link to the device](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/TTGO-T-Deer-Pro-mini-LoRa-433MHz-868MHz-915MHz-Mega328-for-arduino/32948588389.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.27424c4dSUGiJN)"_). However, my main question is that is it possible to install IOTA on such a small device? Or we have to interact with IOTA tangle by a normal computer? I think proposed idea in article has an architecture like this figure: https://imgur.com/a/ZvkgkBu Am I wrong? Thx

Comment: I will answer to the original question. Don't raise more questions in the comments. Open new one(s) if appropriate for this site, otherwise do you own research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `iota.lib.js.powsrvio` in your question is a NodeJS library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/iota.lib.js.powsrvio

> How to use powsrv.io?

To use NodeJS libraries, you need to install NodeJS. That is something you can do on any Linux distribution, for example.

> And what are prerequirements ?

The system must have enough RAM, program memory and computing power to be able to run NodeJS and install npm packages. To use `powsrv.io` as intended, you also need a HTTPS connectivity. This is something you will not have on a device only connected through LoRaWAN.

The device you link to (TTGO T Deer Pro mini LoRa) apparently "for Arduino". I don't know much about Arduino, but according to [this answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/1089) there are some Arduinos that run Linux and can install NodeJS. However, this is not the intended usage of the library - it makes sense to use in on the LoRaWAN base station side, but not on the LoRaWAN data producer side.